# rails console - cannot load custom_require.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm

I have a problem when starting rails console:

```
Loading development environment (Rails 4.1.1)
cannot load such file -- rubygems/custom_require.rb
```

Console is running, except that I cannot require any gem. Require in application is okay.
I would like to test in console with any of gems, do you now what is the problem?

Ruby version

```
ruby 2.1.0p0 (2013-12-25 revision 44422) [x86_64-linux]
```

Thanks.

Comment: you shouldn't need to explicitly require any gem in the rails console.  You only need to type things like `require 'whatever'` when in irb.  What is custom_require.rb?

Comment: ou thank you,i think that gems are not included in console when i was testing something, but it was wrong code. But anyway why there is this message everytime I starting rails console?

Comment: Most likely you misspelled a gem name in your Gemfile can you provide the contents (of your Gemfile) for us please?

Comment: I think it's not the point, because a while ago I create rails new app and start console and it appears again, in every project i have.

Comment: One of your gems installed has a library path that doesn't match the Gemfile name.  It's a common issue but you're not giving us enough information.  Read [this](http://guides.rubygems.org/faqs/#require-fail)

Comment: tell me the absolute path of the file which you want to require and the name of your app folder

Comment: @Anthony thank you for this link, now i know where is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

What version of ruby are you using? 
Trying requiring a gem with relative require on the file.

```
require_relative 'gem_name'
```

Comment: Not working.I edited my question with version of ruby.